# Gmail "add contact" makes you type the name again

Tags: gmail, contacts, google-contacts

I'm logged into Gmail webmail via Chrome on Win7.

I open an e-mail.  The person is not on my contact list, but I want them to be.  I mouse over their name.  A card comes up with their name, e-mail address, picture placeholder, and some links, one of which is `Add to Contacts`.

I click that link.  I'm brought to a page for the new contact, which has their e-mail address.  However, instead of their name, it has large text saying, "Add name."

It's not just a visual glitch: if I go from there to the contact list, sure enough, the e-mail address is there, with no name.

Happens every time.  Why does it not pick up the person's name?  Am I the only one this happens to, and if not, how is there not even apparently a "lab" I could enable that would address this / what can I do to fix this?  Even the cruddiest old webmail interfaces have this feature working correctly...

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward answer: Google is allowing you to give the contact a nickname.

As for why it doesn't default, that's really up to the GMail devs, and you would have to go through Google Support to get anywhere with this.

Comment: They can still 'allow' the same way while providing a sensible default, like any other client...

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have three choices, and depending on urgency/motivation you can use all of them:

1. Copy the name to clipboard bevor clicking on the link
2. Complain in the [Gmail help page](http://support.google.com/mail/?hl=en).
3. Write a [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) script.